# Swift completion block

Tags: ios, swift, block, xcode6

I'm having a hard time understanding a problem I'm having.
To simplify, I'll use UIView method.
Basically, if I write the method

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations:  {() in
        }, completion:{(Bool)  in
            println("test")
    })
```

it works fine.
Now, if I do the same method, but creating a string like so:

```
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations:  {() in
        }, completion:{(Bool)  in
            String(23)
    })
```

It stops working. Compiler error: **Missing argument for parameter 'delay' in call**

Now, here's the strange part. If I do the exact same code as the one that fails, but just add a print command like so:

```
   UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations:  {() in
        }, completion:{(Bool)  in
            String(23)
            println("test")
    })
```

it starts to work again.

My problem is basically the same thing. My code:

```
   downloadImage(filePath, url: url) { () -> Void in
         self.delegate?.imageDownloader(self, posterPath: posterPath)
        }
```

Doesn't work. But if I change to.

```
 downloadImage(filePath, url: url) { () -> Void in
             self.delegate?.imageDownloader(self, posterPath: posterPath)
                println("test")
            }
```

or even:

```
downloadImage(filePath, url: url) { () -> Void in
             self.delegate?.imageDownloader(self, posterPath: posterPath)
             self.delegate?.imageDownloader(self, posterPath: posterPath)
            }
```

It works fine.
I can't understand why this is happening. I'm close to accept that it's a compiler bug.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Closures in Swift have **[implicit returns](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-XID_158)** when they are only made up of a **single expression**. This allow for succinct code such as this:

```
reversed = sorted(names, { s1, s2 in s1 > s2 } )
```

In your case, when you create your string here:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations:  {() in }, completion:{(Bool) in
    String(23)
})
```

you end up returning that string and that makes the signature of your closure:

```
(Bool) -> String
```

That no longer matches what's required by `animateWithDuration`'s signature (which translates to Swift's cryptic `Missing argument for parameter 'delay' in call` error because it can't find an appropriate signature to match).

An easy fix is to add an empty return statement at the end of your closure:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations:  {() in}, completion:{(Bool) in
    String(23)
    return
})
```

Which makes your signature what it should be:

```
(Bool) -> ()
```

Your last example:

```
downloadImage(filePath, url: url) { () -> Void in
    self.delegate?.imageDownloader(self, posterPath: posterPath)
    self.delegate?.imageDownloader(self, posterPath: posterPath)
}
```

works because there are two expressions there, not just one; implicit returns only happen when the closure contains a single expression. So, that closure isn't returning anything and that matches its signature.

Comment: Thanks. But why doesn't it fail if I add String(23) and copy the same line again like: String(23); String(23);  ?

Comment: I was actually in the middle of clarifying that in the answer. See edit.

Comment: Thanks for this answer; helped me figure out why I got a strange "cannot invoke 'animateWithDuration' with an argument list of type..." error. Turned out the fix was exactly the same.